# Microsoft Visual Studio Hotkey waiting for another keypress

Tags: visual-studio

I'm used to Netbeans and all its shortcuts (e.g. ctrl+e to delete a line), but I'm new to Visual Studio, so I don't like its keypress combinations that much.

When I changed all the hotkeys I need (e.g. alt+shift+up/down to move lines up and down), I also tried to set deleting a line to ctrl+e.

The problem is that when I press ctrl+e now, the IDE waits for me to press another key, because there are hotkeys that go like "ctrl+e followed by ctrl+something".

Do I have to disable all the other hotkeys if I just want to use ctrl+e, or can I tell the IDE something like "when nothing is pressed after ctrl+e for 500ms, then dont wait any longer"?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These multi-sequence keystrokes are called *chords*, and Visual Studio uses them because it has so many commands that there would otherwise be nowhere near enough keyboard shortcuts to invoke them all. And no, you cannot set a timeout value.

You have to disable all of the other keyboard shortcuts that involve <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, otherwise the software will have no way of knowing if it should keep waiting for you to press the second part of the chord.

Here's a hint that may make your life easier. When you arrive at the Environment → Keyboard options, don't bother to select anything. Just leave everything at their defaults and click in the "Press shortcut keys" box. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Now, the dialog will give you a list of all the currently-mapped shortcuts that use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

On my installation, all but one of them are specific to the "Workflow Designer". Only one is used by the "Text Editor"—Edit.ToggleWordWrap, which is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Since you will only be deleting lines in the text editor, you don't actually need to worry about unmapping all of the shortcuts for the Workflow Designer scope. You can just set up your shortcut as being specific to the text editor. Stepwise:

1. Remove the keyboard shortcut for Edit.ToggleWordWrap. (You can do this quickly by typing "toggleword" into the "Show command containing" textbox.) Click the "Remove" button.
2. Now, switch to Edit.LineDelete.
3. Change the "Use new shortcut in" combobox to "Text Editor".
4. Click in the "Press shortcut keys" box, and type a good old chordless <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.
5. Click "Assign", and you're done (unless you want to change ToggleWordWrap to something else).